# How send id Company in the controller?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

There is a view of creating a contact

### Create contact

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Contact", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Добавить контакт</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">Surname</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">Name</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">Отчество</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MiddleName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MiddleName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">Phone</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">E-mail</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">Image</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="file" name="uploadImage" />
    </div>
    <p>Company:</p>
    <input type="text" name="name" data-autocomplete-source='@Url.Action("GetSearchValue", "Company")' />
    <p>
       <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
```

}

Company autocomplete with Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {
        var target = $(this);
        target.autocomplete({ source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source") });
    });
});
```

```
    public ActionResult GetSearchValue(string term)
    {
        var models = db.Companies.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(term))
                         .Select(a => new
                         {
                             Id = a.Id.ToString(),
                             value = a.Name,
                             label = a.Name
                         }).ToList();
        return Json(models, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Id company on the page of creating a contact is not displayed. How to create a contact with the company id(one-to-many) value in the Contact controller method Create??
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

Contoller Contact and Model Contact

```
   public ActionResult Create(Contact contact, HttpPostedFileBase uploadImage)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && uploadImage != null)
            {
                byte[] imageData = null;
                // считываем переданный файл в массив байтов
                using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(uploadImage.InputStream))
                {
                    imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(uploadImage.ContentLength);
                }
                // установка массива байтов
                contact.Image = imageData;
                contact.ImageMimeType = uploadImage.ContentType;//DELETE

                db.Contacts.Add(contact);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(contact);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
    }
public class Contact
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Фамилия")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Имя"), Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Отчество")]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression("\\+380+\\d+", ErrorMessage="Введите номер в фортмате +380ХХХХХХХХХ")]
    [Display(Name = "Телефон"), MaxLength(13), Required]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Фото профиля")]
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }

    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Companies { get; set; }
}
```

How I save CompanyId in db with ajax autocomplete
how write in input name company?
[[image: How write Name Company?]]

Comment: Do you handle the autocomplete selection somewhere in your javvascript?

Comment: No. All code is written. How to handle?

Comment: So you're using jQuery autocomplete, right?

Comment: Yes, I using JQuery autocomplete

Comment: Have you seen my answer below? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add a hidden field into your Razor. That hidden field should store the `Id` of the selected company:

```
// I suppose that you have a property named CompanyId in your view model.
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CompanyId, new { data_company_id = string.Empty })
```

In you javascript you need to tell jQuery `autocomplete` widget where to store the selected company `Id`. So you need to do this by handling the `select` event of your `autocomplete` widget:

```
$("[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {
        var target = $(this);
        target.autocomplete({ 
            source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source"),
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $('input[data-company-id]').val(ui.item.value); 
                $('input[name="name"]').val(ui.item.label);
            } 
        });
});
```

Before your need to store the company Id into your the value property of the returned json object like below:

```
public ActionResult GetSearchValue(string term)
{
    var models = db.Companies.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(term))
                     .Select(a => new
                     {
                         value = a.Id.ToString(), // <- this need to be done
                         label = a.Name
                     }).ToList();
    return Json(models, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

After that, your `Create` action will have the selected company `Id`.

Comment: Did so. But in the database null. 
`@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CompanyId, new { data_company_id = string.Empty })
        <input type="text" name="name" data-autocomplete-source='@Url.Action("GetSearchValue", "Company")' />`
Image add in description

Comment: @АнтонЕвсеев can you show us the Create action please

Comment: Add also the model

Comment: add to description

Comment: @АнтонЕвсеев if you put breapoint into `select` event does it hit the function ? If not replaace it with `change`.

Comment: No change//////

Comment: It really weird. Because I tested with a minmalist project and it works :)

Comment: By putting breakpoin into your controller action, what is the value of CompanyId and Company properties?

Comment: I just saw my error. Instead of `ui.value` you should write `ui.item.value`. Just updated my answer.

Comment: It's worked! Thanks! And last question. How after select set Name Company(label)  in the input? Now set Id(value). (i add image in description)

Comment: I updated my answer so you can do that. Just add `$('input[name="name"]').val(ui.item.label);` in select handler

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding the Company Details with an Input field, bind the fetched Company Details with an Dropdown List where Value is Company Id, in your case a.Id and Name or Label is Company Name, a.Name in your case.

In this case the User will get an Option to select the Company from the dropdown list and when data is posted back to the server you will receive company Id in your controller and not the company name.

If you want user to have a search functionlity you can implement that on top of the Dropdown list.

I hope this helps.